# SQL/C# Find Identical NVarchar Values Except for Integer at the End

Tags: sql-server

Working with .NET 4.6.1, C#, SQL Server 2014

I have a custom ID column in SQL that is nvarchar(255)

I need to find records where the values in that column are identical *except* for an integer at the end.

For example:

```
parentunit_childunit
parentunit_childunit1
parentunit_childunit2
parentunit_childunit10
parentunit_childunit33
```

I want to exclude records that have any difference other than the integer.  For example:

```
parentunit_childunit_someotherthing2
parentunit_childunit_somethingelse3
```

I initially tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT CustomId
FROM dbo.CustomUnit
WHERE CustomId LIKE 'parentunit_childunit%'
AND SUBSTRING(CustomId,LEN(CustomId),1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

But that will obviously not exclude the records with additional characters before the integer.

I also tried:

```
SELECT CustomId
FROM dbo.CustomUnit
WHERE CustomId LIKE 'parentunit_childunit_'
AND SUBSTRING(CustomId,LEN(CustomId),1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

But that will exclude records that don't have multiple digits at the end.

I have no way of knowing in advance how many of the characters at the end will be numbers or how many almost-identical records are present.  Numbers anyplace else in the string don't matter.

My ultimate goal is to find the record with the highest integer at the end (where the value is otherwise identical).

If it would be easier to accomplish in C# I'm fine with that.

I'm not able to change the table to split integers into a separate column.

For example, if table contains:

```
CustomId
-------------------------------------
parentunit_childunit
parentunit_childunit1
parentunit_childunit2
parentunit_childunit_someotherthing10
parentunit_childunit_someotherthing11
parentunit_childunit_someotherthing12
parentunit_childunit_somethingelse3
parentunit_childunit_somethingelse4
parentunit_childunit_somethingelse5
parentunit_childunit10
parentunit_childunit33
parentunit_testchild
parentunit_testchild1
parentunit_newchild
parentunit1_newchild1
parentunit1_newchild2
anotherparent_anotherchild
anotherparent_anotherchild1
newparent_childunit5
newparent_childunit6
newparent_childunit7
```

And the user creates another combination of parentunit_childunit the result set should be:

```
Result
-------------------------------------
parentunit_childunit
parentunit_childunit1
parentunit_childunit2
parentunit_childunit10
parentunit_childunit33
```

So that I can get the MAX value and make the new record parentunit_childunit34

Comment: Can you provide an exact example of what your input data and output data would look like?  I'm a bit confused by your example.  Either way, you should be able to do this with some variation of [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in c# using regular expressions to filter the values

The used regex pattern is `(yourfixedtextpart)(\d*)$` where:

- only the texts that match exactly yourfixedtextpart or has yourfixedtextpart followed by numbers at the end
- the fixed text is in group 1
- number is in group 2. This group can be empty. \d* denotes 0 or more occurrences. If you need at least one digit. you can set \d+

In each match we get the numeric part and compared with the maximum found until now. If new max found, we save it. Finally you can return the complete string or only the max number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace findDup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchString = "parentunit_childunit";

            var service = new DataService();
            var data = service.GetData(searchString);
            string foundValue = service.FindHigestDup(data, string.Concat("(", searchString, ")(\\d*)$"));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundValue)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found {foundValue}");
            }
        }
    }

    class DataService {
        public List<string> GetData(string searchString) {
            //you can prefilter some data in SQL
            string sql = @"
                SELECT CustomId
                FROM dbo.CustomUnit
                WHERE CustomId LIKE '" + searchString + "%'";
            return new List<string>  {
                "parentunit_childunit",
                "parentunit_childunit1",
                "parentunit_childunit2",
                "parentunit_childunit10",
                "parentunit_childunit33",
                "parentunit_childunit_someotherthing2",
                "parentunit_childunit_somethingelse3"
            };
        }

        public string FindHigestDup(List<string> data, string pattern) {
            int max = 0;
            bool found = false;
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            string charValue = "";
            foreach (string item in data) {
                var match = regex.Match(item);
                if (match.Success) {
                    found = true;
                    charValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    var intValue = match.Groups[2].Value == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
                    max = Math.Max(max, intValue);
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                return string.Concat(charValue, max.ToString());
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This query will break up the `CustomId` field into parts of `BaseId` and `Number`:

```sql
DECLARE @CustomUnit TABLE (
    CustomId NVARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO @CustomUnit VALUES 
     ('abc')
    ,('abc1')
    ,('abc12')
    ,('abc8173')
    ,('some_value')
    ,('some_value2')
    ,('some_value104')
    ,('some_value9838717654')
SELECT 
    cu.CustomId,
    parts.BaseId,
    parts.Number
FROM @CustomUnit cu
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CustomId) AS FirstDigitIndex
    ) i
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(CustomId, 0, IIF(i.FirstDigitIndex = 0, LEN(cu.CustomId) + 1, i.FirstDigitIndex)) AS BaseId,
            IIF(i.FirstDigitIndex = 0, NULL, SUBSTRING(cu.CustomId, i.FirstDigitIndex, LEN(cu.CustomId))) AS Number
    ) parts
```

It will produce this as output:

```
CustomId                 BaseId         Number    
------------------------ -------------- ----------
abc                      abc            NULL      
abc1                     abc            1         
abc12                    abc            12        
abc8173                  abc            8173      
some_value               some_value     NULL      
some_value2              some_value     2         
some_value104            some_value     104       
some_value9838717654     some_value     9838717654
```

You can then further filter that query to get exactly what you need.